# Understanding queries ( includes, joins, conditions)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In an application i've got the following models:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activity_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :children, through: :activity_items, source: :activity_itemable, source_type: 'Child'
  has_many :parents, through: :activity_items, source: :activity_itemable, source_type: 'Parent'

...
end
```

ActivityItem is used to add participants to an activity

```
class ActivityItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity_itemable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :activity
  has_many :children, through: :activity_itemable, source_type: 'Child'
  has_many :parents, through: :activity_itemable, source_type: 'Parent'
...
end
```

An Activity has a date column: 'activity_date', and others not important here.
An ActityItem has state, activity_id, activity_itemable_type and activity_itemable_id columns.

I've build a "statistic" report for counting the participants ( how many parents were on the activities lists, how many different parents were present etc...)

I've build queries to count, but i have trouble to understand the SQL generated an i need help here to be sure i'm doing the good queries.

Here are some of my queries and my questions:

1- I want to count how many different child (activity_items with type of Child) i have in activity but only in activities older than 2015-12-31

```
Activity.where("activity_date > ?",  "2015-12-31").includes(:activity_items).where("activity_items.activity_itemable_type = ?", "Child").references(:activity_items).distinct.count("activity_items.activity_itemable_id")
```

sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT activity_items.activity_itemable_id)
FROM "activities" LEFT OUTER JOIN
     "activity_items"
     ON "activity_items"."activity_id" = "activities"."id"
WHERE (activity_date > '2015-12-31') AND (activity_items.activity_itemable_type = 'Child')
```

Because there are two conditions on two different tables, isn't more appropriate to use an INNER JOIN to select only the rows matching both conditions?

2- Same query but i'm starting from the other table

```
ActivityItem.includes(:activity).where('activity_date >= ?', "2015-01-01").where(activity_itemable_type: "Child").distinct.count(:activity_itemable_id)
```

Same result, but few strange things. I'dont have to write the where clause like in the query 1. My first attempt was to write:

```
.where('activity.activity_date >= ?', "2015-01-01")
```

But it failed i have to use:

```
.where('activity_date >= ?', "2015-01-01")
```

Finally what is strange is the LEFT OUTER JOIN. The table on the left is activity_items so isn't it supposed to load all the rows from this table?  It's like all the queries i used return the same result like it was acting like INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "activity_items"."activity_itemable_id")
FROM "activity_items" LEFT OUTER JOIN
     "activities" ON "activities"."id" = "activity_items"."activity_id"
WHERE (activity_date >= '2015-01-01') AND "activity_items"."activity_itemable_type" = 'Child'
```

If i use joins instead of includes i got the same results but with INNER JOIN.

Another strange thing: if i don't specify the distinct but just the count(with_attribute_i_want_to_count) the SQL still contains the distinct. But the rails guides on queries tells that it should count only when the given attribute is filled in the database.

I test my queries and the results are ok but i not sure how to interpret and understand the SQL generated.

How do you understand the LEFT OUTER JOIN in this rails exemple?

What should i expect when i launch a query with "includes" and conditions on both tables?

Do you have some documentation to recommend for clarifying my situation?

Thanks for reading this strange question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions.

(1) "Because there are two conditions on two different tables, isn't more appropriate to use an INNER JOIN to select only the rows matching both conditions?"

An inner join would also act as a filter.  With a `left outer join` you can get activities that have no items.

(2) "How do you understand the LEFT OUTER JOIN in this rails example?"

The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "activity_items"."activity_itemable_id")
FROM "activity_items" LEFT OUTER JOIN
     "activities"
     ON "activities"."id" = "activity_items"."activity_id"
WHERE (activity_date >= '2015-01-01') AND "activity_items"."activity_itemable_type" = 'Child'
-------------------------------------------^
```

The noted part of the query is a condition on the second table in a `left outer join`.  That turns the `left outer join` into an `inner join`.

The moral of the story:  don't use a code generator to try to understand SQL.  They produce very specific code that might be nothing like what a person would produce.  For instance, the `distinct` is totally unnecessary in the `select distinct` in both queries.  Neither query uses table aliases, which would improve readability.  And identifies are all escaped, probably specifically to hinder human beings from readily understanding them.

Comment: Hi Gordon thanks for your answer. It helps me to clarify my ideas. Actually i use the standard rails "generator" for those queries because it was really fast for me. But as i'm building more complex queries i decided to dig in the SQL like if i wanna check the output of the generator by curiosity. I think it's time for me to dive in the plain SQL queries. Do you have any readings recommandations or tutorials that would help me? It's not a problem if there aren't related to rails directly.

Comment: Just another small question, when you said that the left outer join turn into an inner join. Is it always true? I mean if a left outer has conditions on both tables will it always be a inner join? Thanks

Comment: If a `where` clause has conditions on the second table in the `left join`, and the conditions filter out `NULL` values, then the `where` clause will produce the same result set as an `inner join`.  They might not have the same execution plans, but the results are the same.